# Saving the UI page when the device shutsdown in xamarin android application

Tags: android, xamarin

I have an android xamarin application running on an custom embedded device. Say I am in page 2 of the application and I reboot the device. Can I launch the same page when the device boots up if I configure the application as a launcher app?

Thanks

Comment: you would need to save the state when the app closes and then do something to restore that state on launch

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I use onSaveInstanceState() to accomplish this?

Comment: Any example will help.

Comment: you could refer to this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-save-an-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state